# Word wrapping in PhpStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

How can I enable *word* wrapping in PhpStorm?

I need to enable it only for some of my files (with extension .txt). Is it possible?

Comment: It's a shame that you can't specifically set it to soft wrap for certain file types. I only ever want to wrap if it's a HTML file, and it would be so much handier if I could set it to do that automatically instead of having to click through the menu each time.

Comment: @Maccath it appears you can do that now. See the "soft-wrap files" setting in PHPStorm.

Answer (score 478, accepted):

**For all files** (default setting for opened files): *Settings/Preferences* → *Editor* → *General* → *Use soft wraps in editor*. You can now specify file names/extensions where this option will be enabled by default:

[image]

---

**For the currently opened file** in the editor: menu → *View* → *Active Editor* → *Use Soft Wraps* *(Note: I've assigned custom <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> + shortcut for that)*

[image]

For quite a while (since v2016 or so) you can also access this option via the context menu for the editor gutter area (the area with line numbers on the left side of the editor):

[image]

*(Note: I have customised this menu quite a bit; by default it has much less items here)*

---

*Search Everywhere* (<kbd>Shift 2x times</kbd>) or menu *Help* → *Find Action...* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> on Windows using the Default keymap) can also be used to quickly change this option (instead of going into *Settings/Preferences*).

[image]

Comment: right click on the left gutter (line numbers area) and choose Soft Wraps. a ver quick way to enable soft wraps per file

Comment: File > Settings > Editor > Use Soft wraps in Editor.

Comment: File > Settings > Editor > General > "Use soft wraps in editor"

Comment: @Ryan that option does not seem to exist anymore. Under **General** the option is not there.

Comment: It is there for me, phpStorm v9.0.2 on ubuntu

Comment: phpStorm for Mac v10.0:
**PhpStorm** > Preferences > Editor > Use Soft wraps in Editor (as opposed to under the File menu)

Comment: I am using PHP Storm on a Mac, 2017.3.4 and for me soft wraps only works in presentation mode.

Comment: @dan No idea unfortunately (Windows user here). As far as I'm aware it works (saw no such tickets/complaints). The only other thing -- it may just not remember the setting when you setup to have only 1 tab opened at a time... so when switching between files it forgets the option...

Comment: Or just tap Left Shift key twice and type "soft wraps" and I will find if for You.

Answer (score 57):

You have to enable Soft Wraps. Find that option through this path.

Menu *View* → *Active Editor* → *Use Soft Wraps*

[image: Wrap words in PhpStorm]

Answer (score 22):

*Right click* on the line number area and choose:

*Soft-Wrap All Files* or *Soft-Wrap Current File*, i.e.:

[image]

Answer (score 16):

- Menu *File* → *Settings* → *Editor* → *Use soft wraps in editor*: to turn them on for all files by default.
- Menu *File* → *Settings* → *Code Style* → *General* → *Wrap when typing reaches right margin*

  .. but that's different (it will make new line).

Comment: this helped me out.  It was driving me mad with the editor auto wrapping my code when I didnt want it to.  I couldnt find the option but this helped so ty ^^.

Comment: This must be really old, i could not find it

Answer (score 11):

In addition to **Settings** -> **Editor** -> **Use soft wraps in editor** I recommend **Use soft wraps in console** and **Use custom soft wraps indent** with a setting of **4** to make the wraps indented to match the line they started on.

Answer (score 11):

In PhpStorm 2019.1.3, it is possible to enable soft wrap for some file types only.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

In PhpStorm 2019.1.3, you should add the file type you want to make soft wrapping on.

Go to *Settings* → *Editor* → *General* → *Soft-wrap files*, and then add any types you want:

[image]

Comment: you can actually use **\*.\*** for all type of file and extension.

Answer (score 6):

You may also want to consider the [Wrap to Column](https://github.com/abrookins/WrapToColumn) plugin, which implements the equivalent to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> in Emacs and <kbd>gq</kbd> in Vim. This may be preferable to having very long lines that are wrapped by the editor.

This plugin can be installed from any [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA)-based IDE by searching for *Wrap to Column*.

It has the additional benefit that you can choose to wrap only sections of text that you want :-)

Answer (score 6):

If using PhpStorm 2019 and higher

[image: PhpStorm word wrapping settings screenshot]

Menu *File* → *Settings* → *Editor* → *General*.

There is the 'Soft-wrap files' input under the 'Soft Wraps' Header.

> *.md; *.txt; *.rst; *.adoc;*

Add the file types to this field in which files you want them to be used.

> *.md; *.txt; *.rst; *.adoc;*.php;*.js

Answer (score 3):

For *word wrapping* in PhpStorm 2019.1.3, just follow below steps:

From the top navigation menu:

*View* → *Active Editor* → *Soft-Wrap*

That's it so simple.

Comment: It is not, you have to do it per file.

Answer (score 2):

WebStorm 10.0.4

For wrapping text/code line by default, but for all types of file:
menu *File* → *Settings* → *Editor* → *General* → section *"Soft Wraps"* → checkbox *"Use soft wraps in editor"*.

Comment: But the question is about PhpStorm. Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

I want to soft-wrap .php files. Putting that in the allowed list still was not working. (For a screenshot, see *[Mohammed Zayan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351608/word-wrapping-in-phpstorm/57689518#57689518)*.)

I entered `*.*` there, allowing all the files (I am fine with that) and soft wrap worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

For *word wrapping* in PhpStorm:

1. Select *File* from the menu
2. From File select *Setting*
3. From Setting, select *Editor*
4. Select *General* from *Editor*
5. In general, checked *Use soft wraps in editor* from the *Soft wraps section*

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer - is this triggered for all files with the same extension?