# Soft wrap by Markdown only

Tags: webstorm, word-wrap

I'd like to have soft wraps in the WebStorm editor only by Markdown files. According to [Word wrapping in phpstorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351608/word-wrapping-in-phpstorm) this can be achieved only with `Menu | View | Active Editor | Use Soft Wraps`. I really don't want to have soft wraps by coding, but I don't want to use the menu every time I open an `.md` file.

Isn't there a way to assign this behavior for example to language or to file type?

Comment: *"Isn't there a way to assign this behavior for example to language or to file type?"* No as it's an IDE-wide setting. It's either On or Off for all files with option to change it for current file manually (and this override is not saved anywhere/valid until file or project is closed). If such option would be supported by `.editorconfig` files .. and if IDE would read it from there .. then it could be done this path as `.editorconfig` *can have* settings that should be applied to certain files only.

Comment: @LazyOne I don't think we have that feature. https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/issues/168

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found an acceptable solution to do this:

1. Go to "Settings" -> "Keymap".
2. Look for "Main menu" -> "View" -> "Active Editor".
3. Assign a keyboard shortcup to "Use Soft Wraps" (for instance: Ctrl + Alt + w).

Now when you are editing a file, use this shortcut and it will enable the soft wraps only for this file.

Comment: Thanks! I will check this at weekend.

Comment: I read it. I knew that it can be done by active editor, so this is almost the same as doing this from menu. I wanted to do this automatically, not manually, but I accept this, since there is no better solution yet afaik.

Comment: While useful, this doesn't answer the question, which is how to have the editor _automatically_ soft-wrap only certain filetypes.

Answer (score 127):

It's 2019, and users of JetBrains apps now have automatic soft-wraps for Markdown documents - rejoice!

Alas it is not enabled by default, so you'll need to visit your preferences and check a box: On WebStorm 2019.2 at least, navigate to Editor > General > Soft Wraps and click your way to Markdown-soft-wrap bliss.

[image: Screenshot of the WebStorm preferences panel]

Comment: I still have the old version, I don't like the annual licensing. For now it is ok, later I'll think about using a different IDE or buying the annual license. It is just not priority now.

Comment: I have version 2020.3.2 and this worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: Cool, that helped! Is there also a way to configure the soft-wrap to happen after a fixed number of characters rather than depending on the viewport?

Answer (score 3):

You can configure this in `.editorconfig` and it will work in any JetBrains IDE that supports `.editorconfig` (hopefully all of them).

```
[*.md]
ij_any_wrap_long_lines = true
```