# PhpStorm - Go to end of line shortcut (IdeaVim)

Tags: phpstorm, ideavim

IdeaVim has [this bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-841), where you can't go the the line's end by typing a dollar sign (<kbd>$</kbd>). You can see it demonstrated here, what happens when I try:

[image: IdeaVim bug demo]

[And here (this gif is too big, so I had to link it).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vosJU.jpg)

Since I'm using IdeaVim, my fingers are far away from the arrow-keys, so <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>→</kbd> isn't an option for something I use so many times during the day.

Is there a way to setup a new shortcut for this motion that works regardless of linebreaks and characters on the line?

--**Addition 1**
I'm on a Mac, so I have no 'End'-key.

--**Addition 2** 
I imagined either for something to put in the `.ideavimrc` file - or for a fix in the PhpStorm-settings. But anything that will take me to the end of the line that I am on (not the visual line due to the soft wrap, but the actual line), will serve as an answer.

Am I the only one out here with this problem? Can others reproduce it (by installing [The IdeaVim-plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/164-ideavim), [enabling soft wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351608/word-wrapping-in-phpstorm) and then going to a very long line (that takes up more than one visual line) and press <kbd>$</kbd>)?

Comment: which version of PhpStorm? I have `PhpStorm 2016.1.2
Build #PS-145.1616, built on May 24, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_76-release-b198 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o` and I am not able to reproduce

Comment: I have `PhpStorm 2017.2.1 built #PS-172.3544.41, built on August 2, 2017. JRE: 1.8.0_152-release 915-b6 x86_64. JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.0`. Wierd, that you can't reproduce it. Are you on a Mac or a Windows?

Comment: I am on Mac, just upgraded to `PhpStorm 2017.2.4
Build #PS-172.4155.41, built on September 15, 2017

JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b11 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.12.6` and it still works. Probably something you have `.ideavimrc` causing this issue? I have tried with and without softwraps and both cases it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>_</kbd>. This is a similar movement to <kbd>$</kbd>—it moves the cursor to the last non-whitespace character on the line.

The bug described seems to mimic the behavior of <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>$</kbd>, which moves the cursor to the end of a *screen* line, not to the actual linebreak, when on a soft-wrapped line. I cannot reproduce this bug in recent versions of JetBrains IDEs (the bug report is from 2014), so it may be worth checking for a possible re-mapping in the *~/.ideavimrc* file.

We can try to reset the mapping of <kbd>$</kbd>. Run the command, `:noremap $ $`, and try the movement again on a problem file (IdeaVim doesn't support `:unmap`). If this works, we can add the command to *~/.ideavimrc*, or try to hunt down the source of the remapping.

If the above doesn't solve the problem, and <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>_</kbd> behaves as expected, we can remap the <kbd>$</kbd> movement to <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>_</kbd> using `:noremap $ g_` .

Comment: `:noremap $ $` solved it, so I added this to my `.ideavimrc`-file: `noremap $ $` and now it works whenever I start PhpStorm. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score -1):

What about using the 'End' key on your keyboard ? This is supposed to go to the end of the current line.

In case of a single long line broken into several sub-lines, pressing the 'End' key from anywhere on a sub-line will go to the end of that sub-line.

To reach the very end of such a line, I suggest pressing the 'End' key as much as needed, or holding the key until it's been reached.

Comment: I'm sorry, - but I am on a Mac, - so I have no 'End'-key. And not to be a stickler, but that wouldn't be the 'Vim'-way anyway. :-/