How do I disable word wrap in PhpStorm, and keep it disabled?
I have tried every which way to disable soft-wraps, but they continue to appear every single time I open a file that extends past the current window.

I've unset the soft-wrap files
I've set soft-wrap files to null
I've set soft-wrap files to random file
I've set the character length to 1000
I've cleared cache & reset settings to default
I've turned off original line breaks

PhpStorm 2024.3.1
Build #PS-243.22562.164, built on December 10, 2024
Runtime version: 21.0.5+8-b631.28 aarch64 (JCEF 122.1.9)
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 15.1.1




Works for me TBH -- see https://stackoverflow.com/q/10351608/783119 . I'd suggest to show your settings for that (screenshot) + how it looks in the actual file (the whole IDE window, ideally -- to see the file type and some other details that might give some hints). P.S. Mind, that changing that option in the Settings/Preferences should not affect currently opened files. Soft-wrap is forced for minified files.

@LazyOne It is happening for every type of file. I've set a keyboard shortcut for un-wrapping, but it's just a pain to do it every single time I open a file.


Is this a local or a remote development? 2) Are you using the Distraction Free mode by any chance?


Did you manage to resolve this issue? If not -- what about those last 2 questions from me?

@LazyOne 1) This is local development. (2) No, not using distraction free mode. It started happening about 6 months ago. I've used phpstorm for the last 8 years or so, and have never had this happen. It's on my work computer and it's a pain to reinstall it, but I think that's what I'll be forced to do. I've gone through every setting, changed and rechanged config, it's driving me mad at this point lol

Very odd then... I do not think the reinstall will do much though (since you can purge all settings even right now). BTW, do you use Settings Sync (when they are synced to your JB account). Anyway: 1) try restoring the default settings first: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-project-and-ide-settings.html#restore-defaults 2) You can also try purging all local settings while the IDE is closed by manually deleting appropriate files: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#clean-up-old-ide-dirs
